# TypeError: window.__TAURI_IPC__ is not a function on Tauri

Tags: rust, tauri

I got TypeError: window.**TAURI_IPC** is not a function when i use revoke imported from "@tauri-apps/api/tauri"
[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5j8B.png)

i have try to reconfigure my tauri.conf.json

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to open the app in a browser?

> You can't open the app url in the browser, it must be in the Tauri window unless you use the tauri-invoke-http crate.

[source](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4332)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34267828)

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed to hear. Thank you @Aftershock I had the app loaded in a browser and was chasing this error, which was irrelevant to the actual problem.

Comment: just to connect dots (or maybe a hint for a response :) ) run `yarn tauri dev` instead of `yarn run dev` https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/3434#issuecomment-1506997809